# Custom back button clicked and items disappear?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a custom back button and when clicked it goes to the previous page but then a button is missing and the size and font of item change. Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">
    <img src="Images/back.png" border="0" 
                style="height: 38px; width: 87px" width="86" > 
</a>
```

Comment: can you show the complete DOM so that I can look at which element is missing

Comment: Solved it using master pages thanks for assistAnce